# apache upload file size override org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase

Tags: java, apache, servlets

I get this error while trying to load file -

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (341297) exceeds the configured maximum (51200)
```

Now, I want to override the FileUploadBase size in my program by inheriting it...How can do it my servlet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to get the same error when i tried to upload file on my tomcat server.
caused by
**Thrown to indicate that the request size exceeds the configured maximum.**

solution goes here.
[Increase Tomcat upload size limit](http://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3585#.VBKO1vmSzik)

webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml
navigate to line 55, you will see the limit :

```
<multipart-config>
   <!-- 50MB max -->
    <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
  </multipart-config>
```

change file-size-threshold to 0 ,Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for Accepting answer, And please try to up the answer and recommend it as useful.